# Laravel psr-0 auto-loading

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

I'm using the standard laravel directory structure that comes out the box. I've added this to the composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
          ....
    ],
      **"psr-0": {
        "CARS": "app/"
        }**
},
```

I've got a View

```
<?php namespace Views;
class MyView {

    public function Build()
    {
        return "Great !";
    }
}
?>
```

and a controller

```
class MyController extends \BaseController {
    public function loadHome() {
       $view = new \Views\MyView;
       return $view->Build();
    }   
}
```

It says Class 'Views\XView' not found.

I've ran composer auto-load once already with the PSR-0 there but now I want to add Controllers and View without re-running the composer and I believe PSR-0 allows me to do that (If I run the composer, it works btw).

Answer (score 5):

You're basically not using `PSR-0`, while trying to use it...

If you tell Composer you have:

```
"psr-0": {
    "CARS": "app/"
}
```

It will look desperately for files in

```
app/CARS/*.php
```

And also will understand that all files on it are under the `CARS` namespace:

So, your class must be in:

```
/whatever/application/app/CARS/Views/MyView.php
```

And must be declared as

```
<?php namespace CARS\Views;

class MyView {

    public function Build()
    {
        return "Great !";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap it up into CARS namespace mate

Comment: I did try and change the namespace in MyView.php to CARS\Views but no joy - same class not found error. However, if I remove the namespace altogether and reference it from the controller with new \MyView, it works ok.

Comment: Checkout Antonios example.

Answer (score 0):

As I reviewed composer version `1.8.6` and I had the same issue I referred to [Docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload)

Under the psr-0 key you define a mapping from namespaces to paths, relative to the package root. Note that this also supports the PEAR-style non-namespaced convention.

**Note** namespace declarations should end in \ to make sure the autoloader responds exactly

```
{
   "autoload": {
       "psr-0": {
         "Monolog\\": "src/",
         "Vendor\\Namespace\\": "src/",
         "Vendor_Namespace_": "src/"
       }
    }
}
```

and here is where I was interested with, The PSR-0 style is not limited to namespace declarations only but may be specified right down to the class level. This can be useful for libraries with only one class in the global namespace. If the php source file is also located in the root of the package, for example, it may be declared like this:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "UniqueGlobalClass": "" }
    }
}
```

**Note**
You need to declare a full path to it for example

the file structure is

```
/myProject
   -/app
   --/Acme
   ---/Repositories
   ----/MyClass
```

So my composer psr-0 will look like

```
"psr-0": {
    "Acme": "app/Acme/"
 },
```

Hope this help someone